# costum redirect after submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect

I have this form: http://lawb.co.il/HTMLPage.html

When someone click on the submit button ("שלח טופס" ) they are automaticaly redirected.

How can I prevent this action after clicking on the "שלח טופס" button, or that the page will redirect to a page that I choose and still I will get the information that people fill in the form?

The code is here http://jsfiddle.net/TCpkb/4/

Can you help me with it pleas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit using AJAX and then redirect manually to your custom page. If you cannot use JavaScript, there is unfortunately no way to control the redirection if you let the user directly submit the HTML form.

Comment: so you said that there is nothing to do? :(

Comment: There is. If you use JavaScript, you can submit that form with an AJAX call, discard their redirection attempt, and then handle the redirection yourself. [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) will help.

Comment: I dont know what AJAX is... I got 2 JS codes and one css file, do you want to see them?

Comment: [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is basically a way to send requests to the server without reloading the page. I'm sorry, but I assumed you were comfortable with writing code, but I understand now you are just embedding other scripts. I don't think I'm going to be able to help, but I hope I have pointed you in a direction you can follow up on.